# Is there a way to change the direction an element's width resizes to?

Tags: html, css

For example if I have a `h1` element with the value "hello" with `background-color: pink;`, if the width of this element is shrunk to 10px it looks like this by default: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4s4S.png .

I am wanting the pink part of the element (the background color) to be on the other side of the `h1` element (closer to where "o" is, not "H").

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried `float: right` on the `h1` element but that moves the element off screen when the width is changed

and

2. I have tried giving `h1`'s width a negative value (unsure why this didn't work).

**My current HTML code:**

`<h1 style="background-color: pink; width: 10px;">hello</h1>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ::after selector of h1 element for this.

```css
h1{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
h1::after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:10px;
  height:100%;
  background:pink;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: Tysm for this! this is a great answer to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a box-shadow for this:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 inset pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```